# Find spectral density of a process

Tags: autocorrelation, stationarity, spectral-analysis

Let $X_t = C \cos(2πw t) + D \sin(2πwt) + U_t$ where $C, D$ and $U_t$ are Gaussian random variables with unit variance, and where all the variables are independent, and $U_t$ is white noise. Determine the integrated spectrum associated with $X_t$.

I first found the autocovariance that is $$\gamma(\tau)=\cos(2 \pi w \tau) $$
From this I can get the spectral density given by :
$$S(f)=\sum_{\tau \in \Bbb Z} e^{-2i \pi f \tau}\cos(2 \pi w \tau)$$

However, I don't know how to deal with this. Thus, I wondered that there might be another way because I dont know if it is possible to find a close expression for the spectral density. Is there a way out ?

Comment: After confirming $S$ is real, replace $\cos(2\pi w\tau)$ by $\exp(2\pi i w\tau)$ (intending to take the real part of the result at the end). The sum becomes very tractable: it can be expressed as a sum of two geometric series.

Comment: @whuber I'll try this thanks

Comment: @whuber Hello again, since the sum is over $\Bbb Z$, won't we have a problem with the geometric series ?